# How do I invoke or dismiss the touch keyboard in WPF using .NET 4.6.2?

Tags: c#, wpf, touch, on-screen-keyboard, .net-4.6.2

Microsoft's release notes for .NET Framework 4.6.2 includes the [following](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/03/30/announcing-the-net-framework-4-6-2-preview/):

*"Soft Keyboard support enables automatic invocation and dismissal of the touch keyboard in WPF applications without disabling WPF stylus/touch support on Windows 10. Prior to 4.6.2, WPF applications do not implicitly support the invocation or dismissal of the touch keyboard without disabling WPF stylus/touch support. This is due to a change in the way the touch keyboard tracks focus in applications starting in Windows 8."*

The [List of Changes](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/master/releases/net462/dotnet462-changes.md) likewise states:

*"Enable automatic invocation and dismissal of the touch keyboard in WPF applications without disabling WPF stylus/touch support on Windows 10 [178044]"*

But I cannot find any indication of HOW to do this, and I cannot find anything in the official API diff that seems to be this.

Can anyone help me find documentation of how to do this thing that I can now allegedly do?

My context is that I have an application that explicitly launches "OSK.exe" when needed. On touch devices with a built-in Windows on-screen keyboard, this results in TWO on-screen keyboards being shown. I want to disable the standard one and only launch "OSK.exe" explicitly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/02/announcing-net-framework-4-6-2/) (especially the comments) should answer your question. The short story is: there is nothing specific to do, but it works only on Win10 anniversary edition.

To disable the soft keyboard, you can do what's indicate in the comments:

[WPF on Windows 7 with touch: hide soft keyboard (and the popup icon that enables it)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37596526/wpf-on-windows-7-with-touch-hide-soft-keyboard-and-the-popup-icon-that-enables)

or

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winuiautomation/2015/04/26/how-and-why-i-added-an-on-screen-keyboard-to-my-windows-store-app/

If in WPF on Windows 10 anniversary edition, you can override automation peer in TextBox:

```
protected override AutomationPeer OnCreateAutomationPeer()
 {
 return new FrameworkElementAutomationPeer(this);
 }
```

On Windows 7 it is enough to put

```
 InputMethod.IsInputMethodEnabled=”False”
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Alas, InputMethod.IsInputMethodEnabled=”False” does not work for me on my Windows 7 machine. :(